# track a image in video and replace with another image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-editing

I have to track a window in a video and need to paste an image on window,I have used camshift to track the window, but it did not track it correct.My window is in brown color so I have given the following color range.
 np.array((110,0,0)--lower
 np.array((130,255,255)--higher..

I have red many documents in opencv but not able to figure out which method to follow.I am using opencv2.4.9 with python.

Below is the code which I tried.Please help me out to figure out the exact location of window.*emphasized text*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("myvideo.mp4")
# take first frame of the video
ret,frame = cap.read()
#print frame
#print ret
# setup initial location of window
r,h,c,w = 157,40,337,40 
track_window = (c,r,w,h)

# set up the ROI for tracking
roi = frame[r:r+h, c:c+w]
hsv_roi =  cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_roi, np.array((110,0,0)), np.array((130,255,255)))

roi_hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv_roi],[0],mask,[255],[0,255])
cv2.imshow('img2',roi_hist)

#print roi_hist

cv2.normalize(roi_hist,roi_hist,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

# Setup the termination criteria, either 10 iteration or move by at least 1 pt
term_crit = ( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1 )
i = 1
while(1):
    ret ,frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        i += 1
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        dst = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv],[0],roi_hist,[0,255],1)

            # apply meanshift to get the new location
        ret, track_window = cv2.CamShift(dst, track_window, term_crit)
        #print track_window
        # Draw it on image
        x,y,w,h = track_window
        img2 = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), 255,2)
        cv2.imshow('img2',frame)

        k = cv2.waitKey(200) & 0xff
        if k == 27:            
            break
        else:
          #  print "comes here2";
            cv2.imwrite(str(i)+"test.jpg",frame)
            #break

    else:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: why did you choose hue 110 - 130 ? can you post a sample image with that brown rectangle?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1gMUc.jpg .I have to track the blue color rectangle in my video.

Comment: The interior of the blue boundary is the region you want to track? Where is there a brown color? :D  do you want to track the window of that door or the visible part of whats behind it?

Comment: Yes.. I want to track the window of that door(square box in door). the door keeps moving in my video.. so that window location keeps changing..  I have to get the coordinates of that window in each video frame and need to place a photo on that window.

Comment: thank you so much for your fast response..Yes.. I have to track the window of that door(a square in window). door in the video keeps moving so the window location also changing. I want to get the coordinates of window in each video frame and need to replace with a photo.. you can compare this http://i.stack.imgur.com/CU9Dl.jpg image with previous image to see the differnce in window location.

Comment: You cant only track the interor (glass) part of the window visually, since its content changes dependinh on whats behind the glass. Try tracking the outer frame instead and then get the inner one.

Comment: ok.. which color range I should give? Can I follow the same method ?

Comment: You can try it. Easiest way to choose the color would be to click on the location/color you want to track and extract those pixels color automatically or print it to terminal and hardcode the value after extraction.

Comment: Hi Micka,I have extracted the pixel color from colorzila and used that pixel for tracking.But it did not help. Can I track using any other method like plotting the area which I want to track?

Comment: Did you know that opencv hue values are divided by 2 (because range 0..360 isnt covered by a byte)? Typical simple tracking methods are block-matching and histogram matching.

Comment: Yes.. I have changed my hue value divided by 2..I have given the following color range for tracking.. np.array((42,29,29)) and np.array((98,180,180)).. but still it is not tracking properly..

Comment: does the same method (with adjusted color values) work if you try to track a red dot on green background?

Comment: does `mask` show the desired region?

Comment: No..I saved the mask image. It is a black image with some white dots.this is my mask image.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/toARa.jpg